# Google Docs with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to edit word documents/spreedsheets like it happens in Google docs . Can i integrate Google docs into my asp.net application ? 
Is it possible for me to save this edited document on to my server instead of saving it at the google account ?

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i integrate Google docs into my asp.net application ?

Google provide [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

> Is it possible for me to save this edited document on to my server

Yes, [see `get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)

> instead of saving it at the google account ?

You can't let people use the Google Docs WYSIWYG editors and save to your system directly. They'd have to save to their Google account and then you could download the file.